# Read a txt file date 00-00-000

Tags: php, text-files

I trying to read a text file.

This is an example of my text file:

> "20130228","0000079511","ESTEVES PAIVA TERESA HELENA","","4","PAGO
>   UNICO","","","","","",0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,2000.00,"20121213"

as you can imagine I have this two date 20130228 and 20121213, and fifth column is a number, but when I read the file and fill the table on my database I get 00-00-0000 in every date and 0 instead the number 4.

Here is my code for read and insert the information in the table:

```
if ($type == "text/csv") {
            move_uploaded_file($temp, "upload/$name");

            $fp = fopen("upload/$name",'r') or die("no se puede abrir el archivo");

                do { 
            if ($data[0]) { 
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO contacts (fecha_pago, cedula_alumno, nombre_alumno, mencion, codigo_forma) VALUES 
                    ( 
                        '".addslashes($data[0])."', 
                        '".addslashes($data[1])."', 
                        '".addslashes($data[2])."'
                        '".addslashes($data[3])."'
                        '".addslashes($data[4])."' 
                    ) 
                "); 
            } 
        } while ($data = fgetcsv($fp,1000,",","'"));
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: I'd recommend fixing your indentation, so it is clear what brace lines up with which construct. Also, what value does `$data` have during the first run of the `do` loop? If it is undefined, then I wonder if that loop should be a `while`, rather than a `do...while`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the date, that is, parse the value of $data[0] before you're performing an INSERT. MySQL, which I'm guessing you're inserting into, will accept dates in the format 2012-12-31, but not 20121231.

So consider doing

```
$parsedDateYear = substr($data[0], 0, 4); 
$parsedDateMonth = substr($data[0], 4, 2); 
$parsedDateDay = substr($data[0], 6, 2); 

$finalDate = $parsedDateYear . "-" . $parsedDateMonth . "-" . $parsedDateDay;
```

And use $finalDate in your INSERT statement.

Comment: Thanks alex, but for example is the date is 20130228 I'm getting $finalDate = 2048;

Comment: That's because I screwed up and used + for string concatenation :) Sorry, I've been doing too much Python lately. Fixed in the answer.